# Is there R code for moving the focus to the RStudio console?

Tags: rstudio

I am constantly typing into the edit window of RStudio after my code completes execution, when my intention is to provide some input in the console window. Is there R code that could be executed that would automatically move the focus to the console window of RStudio?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In RStudio, go to the menu: Tools > Global Settings.  In Global Settings, choose "Code" on the left and check the box that says "Focus console after executing from source."

If you don't want to change this global option, these keyboard shortcuts can make switching between the console and editor in RStudio much faster:

- Ctrl+1 moves focus to the source editor
- Ctrl+2 moves focus to the console

In addition, Alt+Shift+k brings up a list of most keyboard shortcuts

Comment: Yes, but if I remember to do that all I have to do is click in the console window somewhere. I am looking for R code I could embed in my script that will automatically shift the focus to the console so any keyboard strokes go to the console and not corrupt the code.

Comment: @Ernie - I think I found what you were looking for and updated my answer.  Please see above.

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you not look for a shortcut but for code, RStudio has the following command

```
rstudioapi::executeCommand('activateConsole')
```

See also [RStudio IDE Commands](https://docs.rstudio.com/ide/server-pro/rstudio_ide_commands/rstudio_ide_commands.html)